# List Users with PHP / HTML / Mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to make a private web list with my user informations.

But im having problems doing that..
I need my website list members by ID from database with this informations

id database reference (Hided) - Name - DiscordID - SteamID - Email

And i need this div : `<div class="home-barra"> USER INFO </div>`
got copied and paste all time when retrieve new users.

Im still learning php coding

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'webaccount';
$DATABASE_PASS = '***********';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase';
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT password, email, steamid, discordid FROM accounts WHERE id = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($password, $email, $steamid, $discordid);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();


?>
```

```
       <div class="home-container07">

<-- This need to be copied

            <div class="home-barra">
              <div class="home-container08">
                <span class="home-text07">Nome: <?=$username?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="home-container09">
                <span class="home-text08">Discord: <?=$discordid?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="home-container10">
                <span class="home-text09">SteamID64: <?=$steamid?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="home-container11">
                <span class="home-text10">Email: <?=$email?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
---->

          </div>
```

Comment: Use the same way as in the code you posted, but use a loop that calls `$stmt->fetch()` for each user and shows the corresponding div.

Comment: `while ($stmt->fetch()) { ... }`

Comment: It would be so much easier for you if you used PDO instead of mysqli. If you don't have any good reason to use mysqli, please switch over. Else, even in mysqli, you can do it simpler with `get_result()` or even better `execute_query()`

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, thanks Barman!
Can be closed!

I added a query to my php code

```
$query = "SELECT id, username, discordid, steamid, email FROM accounts";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$users = array();

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $users[] = $row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

After that i edited my html code like this:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <div class="home-barra">
            <div class="home-container08">
                <span class="home-text07">Nome: <?php echo $user['username']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="home-container09">
                <span class="home-text08">DiscordID: <?php echo $user['discordid']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="home-container10">
                <span class="home-text09">SteamID64: <?php echo $user['steamid']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="home-container11">
                <span class="home-text10">Email: <?php echo $user['email']; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Seems fetch have different ways to work.

Comment: Fetch() works the same every time. You've just used it differently!